Non-zero generalized eigenvalues of permuted accretive matrix
I want to show the following statement:
Let $ A\in \mathbb{C}^{2n \times 2n} $ be strictly accretive, i.e. $ Re \langle {Av,v} \rangle>0~ \forall v\in\mathbb{C}^{2n}$, and let J be the following hermetian and selfinverse block-matrix:
$$
  \begin{array}{l@{{}={}}c}
  \text{J =} & \left(\begin{array}{@{}cc@{}}
     0 &  -iI_n \\ iI_n & 0
  \end{array}\right)
  \end{array}
$$
where $I_n$ is the identity.
Then every non-zero generalized eigenvector $v\in $ker$(\lambda I_{2n} -JA)^{2n}, \lambda\in$ spec(JA) of JA has the property, that at least one of the first n components of v is non-zero. Equivalently, the projection $$
  \begin{array}{l@{{}={}}c}
  \text{N =} & \left(\begin{array}{@{}cc@{}}
     I_n &  0 \\ 0 & 0
  \end{array}\right)
  \end{array}
$$
onto the first n components is injective on all generalized Eigenspaces.
Here is what I have already proven:

The eigenvalues of JA have non-zero real part, and exactly half of them have positive real part.
The statement holds for $n \leq 2$.
The projection N is injective on the subspace ker$(\lambda I_{2n} -JA)^{2}$ for any eigenvalue $\lambda$, i.e. the statement holds if the size of the jordanblock of $\lambda$ is less than 3. This follows from a brute-force computation, which is too expansive for bigger jordanblocks.
Any eigenvalue $w = (w_1, w_2) \in \mathbb{C}^{2n} \cap$ ker$(\lambda-JA)$ (not a generalized eigenvalue) has Im$\langle w_1, w_2\rangle \neq 0$ with sign(Im$\langle w_1, w_2\rangle ) = $sign(Re$(\lambda)$). If one could extend this property to generalized eigenvalues, the statement would follow.

I would also like to mention that I am convinced that the statement is true, as I have computed countless examples using matrixcalc.org even for higher dimensions.
Any help is much appreciated. I'd also be glad for any partial results.

After spending 30 hours on this problem before posting, Ifound the solution within 20 minutes... thats just classic.
Anyway, heres the answer:
Assume $Nv = 0$ and $(\lambda-JA)^{2n}v = 0$.
Claim: $$\lim_{t->\infty} \exp(-sign(Re(\lambda))\cdot tJA)v = 0. $$
Define $E_t := \exp(-sign(Re(\lambda))t \cdot JA)$.
Now using the claim, we can compute (note that the first n components of v are zero and that $J = J^*, J^2=1$)
\begin{split}
0 &= |\langle Jv , v\rangle |= |\langle J E_0 v , E_0 v\rangle| \\
&= |\int_{0}^\infty  \partial_t\langle J E_t v , E_t v\rangle dt |
 \\
&= |\int_{0}^\infty -sign(Re(\lambda))\langle J^2 A E_t v , E_t v\rangle -sign(Re(\lambda))\langle J   E_t v , JA E_t v\rangle ~dt |
\\
&= |\int_{0}^\infty  Re(\langle A E_t v , E_t v\rangle) dt |
\\
&\geq \int_{0}^\infty   |E_t v|^2 dt,
\end{split}
by the accretivity of A.
Thus $E_t v$ must vanish for almost every $t\geq0$, but because $E_t v $ is continuous in t, we even get $v=E_0 v = 0$. This proves the statement.
Proof of the Claim:
For this let $SIS^{-1} = JA$ be the Jordan normal form of JA and decompose the Jordanblock matrix $I = D+\eta$, where D is the diagonal part and $\eta$ is the nilpotent part of I. We can assume that one of the columns of S is equal to v, as v is a generalized eigenvector. Let v be equal to the k-th column of S, $1\leq k\leq2n$. The (k,k)-th entry of D must then be $\lambda$. Now
\begin{split} 
\exp(-sign(Re(\lambda))t \cdot JA)v &= S~ \exp(-sign(Re(\lambda))t \cdot\eta)~\exp(-sign(Re(\lambda))t \cdot D)~ S^{-1}v \\&= S~ \exp(-sign(Re(\lambda))t \cdot\eta)~\exp(-sign(Re(\lambda))t \cdot D) ~e_k 
\\&= S~ \exp(-sign(Re(\lambda))t \cdot\eta) ~e^{-sign(Re(\lambda))t\cdot\lambda} e_k \to 0, ~~t \to \infty, 
\end{split}
because $sign(Re(\lambda))\cdot\lambda$ has positive real part.
